# DVD Drive can read a DVD title and file contents (very slowly) but not play DVDs

Tags: windows-7, video, dvd

I've been able to watch DVDs in the past on this computer when it was running XP.  I recently upgraded to windows 7 and haven't watched a DVD since then.

I put a DVD in and it took quite a long time but windows finally found the disk title, and I was able to explore directories (saw folder like VIDEO_TS).  The problem is when I try to have video players play the DVD I just get an error in VLC.  It wouldn't tell me the exact error (said to check the log and I don't know where that is).

Do I have to install some special drivers/certs in windows 7 to play video?

Comment: Tried another DVD and it also didn't work.  Tried both those DVDs in a TV DVD player and they both work.

Comment: What version of Windows 7 do you have? If you have Home Premium, Professional or Ultimate there's something wrong since they have Media Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLC can play DVDs regardless of other codecs in Windows, it is self-contained in the program. Windows Media Player and Media Center can also play DVDs. I would try them as well to rule out a bad VLC install.

If that fails, try a different disk. You may have a bad DVD.

If that still fails you may have a faulty drive.

Edit: Reading your comments, it sure sounds to me like you have a faulty drive.

Comment: Was faulty drive.